# Ensuring unique elements in a nested ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array which can have N nested array where N can contain M arrays where both N and M are >= 1. Some examples include the following:

```
[[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[2,1,1]]]
```

or

```
[[[1,2,3]],[]]]
```

and finally

```
[[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[2,1,1]], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]]
```

I need something that returns a boolean true or false if there is a duplicate value for the 0<sup>th</sup> element in a nested array, the issue is the composite array is not the unique identifier. Only the 0<sup>th</sup> element in each value array such as `[1,2,3]` or `[3,4,5]`, in this case the integers `1` and `3`, are what I need a unique against. so in the case of the last array, `[1,1,1]` and `[1,2,3]` would clash as the `1` is repeated.

What's the best way to iterate through this type of nesting and signal `true` or `false` on whether there are duplicates?

Comment: `Array#uniq` doesn't return true or false

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get exactly what you need, but if I am correct then what about:

`elements = [[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[2,1,1]], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]].map(&:first).map(&:first)`
then
`elements.length == elements.uniq.length`

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def uniq_prime_elements?(arr)
  prime_elements = arr.map(&:first).map(&:first).compact
  prime_elements.length == prime_elements.uniq.length
end
```